# How to Display a Single Image Gallery per Album in Content Teaser?

Tags: 7, views, media, entities

I have made a Hierarchical Photography site using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) and [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og).

The Hierarchy is as follows:

- Top-Level: Category (e.g. - SCENIC, STREET SCENES, MODELS )
- Sub-Level1: ALBUMS | (e.g."BROOKLYN" and "Mid-Manhattan | July 2016" under STREET SCENES Category)
- Sub-Level2: IMAGE GALLERY (e.g. "Commercial and Residential" and "Midtown Streets" under MANHATTAN Album)

Using Views, I am able to display a preview using a **single image** from the Gallery, of each Image Gallery under its respective Album.  See attached "album view" screenshot..
[image: album view]

One the Category Level, I am trying to create a preview image of each Album using a **single image** from **one** of the image galleries in each Album to represent that Album on the Category page, but instead it displays ***all the image galleries*** from each album.  See attached 'category view" screenshot....
[image: category view]

In both views, I am using Panels on the pages to help structure them.

Here is my View for the Category Level:
[image: Category Level Album Teaser View]

and my ALBUM TEASER VIEW

[image: Album Level Image Gallery Teaser View]

and finally my Image Gallery View....

[image: Image Gallery Level View]

Any ideas on how to ensure only one Image Gallery per Album appears on the Category Level when using Content:Teaser?  Thank You!

Comment: Happy to see that you seem to like my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Drupalizer!  You don't need any special coding or modules to fix this.  I figured it out.  So basically, I just needed to create a NEW view of the Album Image Gallery Teaser with the same settings except for the Pager which I made to be "Display a specified number of items | 1 item".

Then I use this view as the Content Teaser for the Category Level and the Content-type 'ALBUM" I set the teaser display to be this EVA view.

See attached screenshot ...

[image: Album Preview Screenshot]